# merge multiple YAML files under a new field

Tags: yaml

I have several YAML files representing the pieces of a whole.  I want to merge them under a new field ("guests") that declares the whole.

file1.yml

```
name: johnny
age: 23
```

file2.yml

```
name: sally
age: 21
```

output.yml

```
guests:
  - name: johnny
    age: 23
  - name: sally
    age: 21
```

tools like `yq` make merging/overwriting easy, but I can't find any that helps me nest values under new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool you are looking for comes with several different names and
are called programming languages or scripting languages. I recommend
you use Python with `ruamel.yaml` installed. (disclaimer: I am the author of
that package).

Once you have that you can do:

```
python -c "import sys, ruamel.yaml; yaml=ruamel.yaml.YAML(); yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2); yaml.dump(dict(guest=[yaml.load(open(f)) for f in sys.argv[1:]]), sys.stdout)" file*.yml > output.yml
```

To get the desired output.

A few notes:

- YAML files should have the [`.yaml` extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) unless your filesystem doesn't support that.
- By default sequence elements are indented two spaces and the dash has no offset within that (i.e. would align with the `g` of guests. Hence the `yaml.indent()` call.
- Any comments on the key-value files of your input file would be preserved **but not automatically pushed out** to the right from their original starting column unless necessary because of a mapping value getting in the way. Adjusting that is possible, but I would not recommend trying that in a one-liner.
- If you need to preserve quotes add `yaml.preserve_quotes = True;` in the one-liner
- If any of your YAML files contain multiple YAML documents, the above will fail. You would need to think about how to combine the documents, and use a `try` `except` clause to fall back to `yaml.load_all()` for documents that do (it would be a good idea to abandon the one-liner in favour of a multiline Python program at that point).

---

You can also do the above using the `yaml` commandline utility (installable with `pip install ruamel.yaml.cmd>=0.5.0`):

```
yaml from-dirs --sequence ./*.yml | yaml map --indent 2,4,2 guest - > output.yml
```

but this is a two step process (first combining multiple yaml files as root level sequence, then pushing that sequence to be a value for mapping), and thus twice as slow as the one-liner.

Comment: Thanks @anthon, I was hoping to avoid any language libraries and find a compiled solution that doesn't require specific language.  But if there's not I'll likely take your approach with a simple go binary.  If no one knows an existing one I'll accept this as best answer

Comment: I already had a utility that could do some YAML file combination. I updated it so it can create a mapping at the root level with specified key and content another YAML stream (see updated answer).